# How to automatically generate a unique random slug

Tags: posts, permalinks, slug

I have tried to create a function that generates a random slug when a post is created. I am a bit worried that the function generates non unique strings as slugs. How can I solve this?

The function looks like:

```
add_filter('name_save_pre','unique_slug', 0);

function random_string() {
    $length = 6;
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $string = '';    
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}

function unique_id($slug) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb -> get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_post WHERE post_name = '" . $slug . "' && post_status = 'publish' && post_type = 'post'");   
}

function unique_slug($slug) {
    if($slug) return $slug;

    $random_slug = random_string();
    if(!unique_id($random_slug)){
        //what to do here?
    }
    else {
        return $random_slug;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this plugin that should do the trick: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-hashed-ids/

Answer (score 5):

Use the function [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_unique_post_slug/). Do not reinvent the wheel, this one is quite tricky.

Usage:

```
$unique_slug = wp_unique_post_slug( 
    $slug,
    $post_ID, 
    $post_status,
    $post_type, 
    $post_parent 
);
```

Then you can test if `$slug === $unique_slug` and generate a new one if the test fails.

You can find the function in `wp-includes/post.php`. It ends with a filter `'wp_unique_post_slug'`, so you can still adjust the return value if you don’t like it.

Comment: Here is the full documentation in the Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug

Comment: @AndrewOdri Unfortunately, this is less than the plain code will tell you. I have added a link to queryposts.com’s docs. Hm, maybe I should write an extended documentation …

Comment: @tocscho Heheh, I guess "full" was the wrong word, I should've gone with "official" :P The querypost.com documentation is great though :)

Comment: I am trying to create a random permalink structure that automatically generates a page_name (or slug). E.g. www.domain.tld/xc34sd/ (where the slug is xc34sd) instead of having the post_title or post_id in the slug.

The problem is that i don't want to have an existed slug with an added suffix. E.g. www.domain.tld/xc34sd-2/

Is this something I can use the  wp_unique_post_slug for?

Comment: @Erikm See my update. Just test if the function has changed the slug.

Comment: I don't get it to work. Maybe the unique validation is delayed?

Comment: This creates a unique slug but not a random slug. I used this and my new post slug was, "a-new-post-5" and when I call `wp_unique_post_slug` it returned the same value. So it is unique but not random or obfuscated.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I "creates" nothing. I left the algorithm out. You have to implement your own, depending on the specific requirements.

Comment: So you're saying to use the function to check if his random value is unique?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Yes, exactly. If it isn't, WP will add a number, like `-2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how a unique random slug can be generated.

```
function randomSlug() {
    $length = 5;
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $slug = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= substr( $chars, wp_rand( 0, strlen($chars) - 1 ), 1 );
    }
    return $slug;
}

function slugExists($slug) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '$slug'")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function uniqueRandomSlug() {
    do {
        $randomSlug = randomSlug();
        $slugExists = slugExists($randomSlug);
    } while ( $slugExists );

    return $randomSlug;
}
```